# Capture audio being played from android device

Tags: android, audio

I can't seem to find out how to do this, perhaps it can't be done for security reasons.

I'd like to be able to capture the audio being played on the device (regardless of what app generates it, etc..) as a stream which could then be manipulated/transferred.

For a bit of background, it's actually going to be transferred out wirelessly to another device on the network, with either WiFi or Bluetooth, probably.

Any pointers on what parts of the API might let me do that, if it's actually possible?

Thanks

PS. My source device is Jelly Bean.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no loop back audio source that will let you record the sounds being generated by the device. The best you can do is record everything and hope your ambient noise isn't too bad.

Comment: Ah, I was hoping for an Airplay style thing, but I wanted it phone wide. Don't think the quality would be good enough this way though. Thanks.